# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid set one value for all rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

My goal is to have a button that when user clicked it, it will prompt text input. Once closed, the value inputted in prompt text will be assign/display to all the rows in a given column. So for example, I inputted '9'. Once dialog page closed, All 10 rows from column A of Interactive Grid will have '9' as a value. This is to lessen the user typing the same value for multiple rows.

Comment: So how does the user get different values when that is needed?

Comment: They gonna type it one by one. But that is very seldom.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, user enters the page that contains an interactive grid and starts entering values; you'd want to use the same value for some column in all rows user enters.

If that's so, then don't reinvent the wheel, but:

- navigate to interactive grid's column that should have the same value throughout all rows
- go to its properties
- set the **Duplicate copies existing value** property ON

Therefore, user would enter that value only for the first row and simply duplicate that row.

---

Alternatively:

- create a page item (let's call it P1_DEFAULT_VALUE)

  - set it to "Submit when ENTER pressed" (or create a submit button which would do the same; because, item's value has to be in session state, otherwise you can't use it)
- navigate to interactive grid's column that should get value entered into P1_DEFAULT_VALUE
- go to its properties
- scroll down to **Default** section
- set

  - type = Item
  - Item = P1_DEFAULT_VALUE

Doing so, column would "inherit" page item's value for each row entered.

Comment: The column was not always to be duplicated. But there's an option to duplicate when they want to, even if that column has already a value. As long as it not submitted they can still modify it.